# deactivate jquery click function when inside a specific div

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a body click function that creates some cool musical circles on the background of a website. I need the click function to deactivate (ie not work) when you are clicking inside the 960px wrapper of the website - otherwise loads of circles appear behind links when you click on the menu etc.

All my code is inside the following:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {

}
```

The div I need to deactivate this on is #wrapper-container

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `target.id` to exclude that particular element from the click event.

Try,

```
$('body').click(function(e) {   
   if(e.target.id != "wrapper-container")
      {

      }
 }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKnzK/1/)

---

Update for situation asked by @Json p

If user directly clicks on the `#wrapper-container` element, The first check itself fails and control will go out of that `if statement`. Its a kind of short circuit implementation.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {          
  if(e.target.id !="wrapper-container" &&
  $(e.target).parents('#wrapper-container').length == 0)  
      {
               alert('you are out of wrapper.!')
      }
 });
```

### [Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GKnzK/2/)

Comment: What if the target is an element inside the wrapper-container div?

Comment: @JasonP oh.. :) Wait one min. I'll find a solution for that.

Comment: PSL's answer has the solution.

Comment: Thanks every one - have got a solution that works now :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$('#wrapper-container').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: i guess you mean to stop propagation instead

Comment: Good catch, was in a hurry and typed too quickly. I did mean that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a check using [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which will take care of any descendant of `#wrapper-container` as well.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {   
      if(!$(e.target).closest("#wrapper-container").length){ //check if the element is wrapper-container or any descendant of it if so do nothing.
      //Do the stuff for others
      }
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrtzc/)**

Comment: What if the target is `"#wrapper-container"`? Closest doesn't include it. Well, I can be misstaken aswell. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes closest will consider that as well. It tests itself or any or its grandparents for the existance of the selector.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon _For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector **by testing the element itself** and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._ http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I see, here you go, +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id='wrapperFoo'>foo</div>

<div id='wrapperBar'>bar</div>


$('#wrapperFoo').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('hi');
});

$('#wrapperBar').off('click', function (e) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5kc2Y/)